# Does CMOS J/K trigger need pull-up resistor

Tags: cmos, trigger

I want to use J/K trigger and I was told that usually IC outputs need pull-up resistor, but if I understand it correctly the following J/K trigger is based on CMOS: [TI J/K trigger](http://www.ti.com/product/CD4027B?keyMatch=CD4027BPW&tisearch=Search-EN-Products) 
And it seems to me that CMOS is capable of making both low and high signal, so there is no need for pull-up resistor, right?

Comment: All CMOS *inputs* which are not constantly driven high and low, need a pull-somewhere-resistor.

Comment: @rdtsc the OP is talking about an output pull-up resistor not an input pull-up. Answer - the 4027 doesn't need a pull-up o/p resistor but some CMOS gates do so always check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for a pull-up or pull-down resistor on CMOS outputs (unless they are open-drain). Inputs should always have a pull-up, pull-down or be connected a valid logic level (another output or a supply rail, usually).

Answer (score 1):

The datasheet for the [CD4027B](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4027b.pdf) does **not** indicate that the outputs are open-drain.  Therefore no pull-up resistor to a DC power source is needed at the output.